# Exception while uploading large file using backload file uploader

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, file-upload, large-file-upload, backload

I am using backload file uploader to upload files, its working fine with files with around 200-300 mb but for larger files 700-1000 mb, its failing and not even throwing proper (its going into handler_StoreFileRequestException but passing parameter as null) exception.

it first shows loading progress bar properly on page and keep loading and once it finish, during debugging its not hitting handler_StoreFileRequestStarted and directly hitting handler_StoreFileRequestException and in that their is parameter StoreFileRequestEventArgs which is comming null in this case.

to support big files i have made some changes in web config like:

```
<system.web>
       <httpRuntime executionTimeout="5000" maxRequestLength="1073741824"/>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
```

but still facing issue..

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

To upload large files in smaller [chunks](/questions/tagged/chunks), set the `maxChunkSize` option to a preferred max size in [bytes](/questions/tagged/bytes):

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: 10000000 // 10 MB
});
```

For chunked uploads to work in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) versions 4 thru 6 ([xhr](/questions/tagged/xhr) upload capable Firefox versions prior to Firefox 7), the multi-part option also has to be set to false
(see the Options documentation on maxChunkSize for an explanation).

Further details available on [Github repo](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads)